# How to combine multiple SQL queries into 1 and output it as PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am building something that is essentially a simple blog platform in PHP and MySQL.

Like almost every blog, the index page will basically pull all the posts from the database and loop them onto the page. I have that figured out.

Each post will have an unknown number of tags associated with it. I want to be able to echo out those tag names along with each post.

What I am doing now is running another query for each post that uses the post's id to find all the tags for that post. I'm including this query in the original loop that gets each post. So essentially, if there are 100 posts returned, I would be running an additional query for EACH of those 100 posts... which is a lot for one page obviously. I know there has to be a better way to handle this.

But how do I get an unkown number of posts, and an unknown number of tags for each of those posts, in one query. And how then do I loop through them in PHP once I have them. My guess is to return them in some sort of nested array???

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
function get_all_posts() {
    global $pdo;    
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT content, id FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC');   
    $query->execute();
    $posts = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $posts;
}
```

And then I echo those results like such:

```
    <?php $posts = get_all_posts(); foreach ($posts as $post): ?>   
        <div class="post-box">
            <p><?php echo $post['content']; ?></p>
            <ul>
                <?php $tags = get_all_tags_per_post($post['id']); foreach ($tags as $tag): ?>   
                    <li><?php echo $tag['name']; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.post-box -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see in that, inside of each returned post, I'm running another query to get the tags:

```
function get_all_tags_per_post($pid) {
    global $pdo;    
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT t.name AS name, t.id AS tid FROM tags AS t JOIN posts_tags AS pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id WHERE pt.post_id = :pid ORDER BY tid ASC'); 
    $query->bindValue(':pid', $pid);
    $query->execute();
    $tags = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $tags;
}
```

I want to combine those two queries, essentially, and then be able to print the output onto my page in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Why not join `Posts` with the other tables?

```
SELECT  t.name AS name, 
        t.id AS tid,
        p.id as pid,
        p.content
FROM    tags AS t 
        INNER JOIN posts_tags AS pt 
            ON pt.tag_id = t.id 
        INNER JOIN posts AS p
            ON p.id = pt.post_id
WHERE   pt.post_id = :pid 
ORDER   BY p.id DESC, t.id ASC
```

Comment: is it ok with the 'AS' in the 'INNER JOIN posts_tags AS pt'? Or should it be 'INNER JOIN posts_tag pt'?

Comment: @n3ISe `AS` in an optional keyword. Although it is a good practice to put it to avoid confusion. Anyway, I'll update the answer.